# Ionic - Problem using two way binding to change a style. As example I am using background-color

Tags: ionic-framework, two-way-binding

I think I have a very basic problem but I can't resolve it. So what I am trying to do is to implement a button in Ionic that when pressed change the style of a style. To keep it simple for now I try and change the background color of a div. However, it does not work neither does it give an error. (I use console page of browser to view changes, look for errors etc)

The code in the card.page.html page is

```
<ion-button
(click)="setStyle('red')"
[style.--background]="'pink'"
>
Some Button
</ion-button>
```

The code in the card.page.ts is

```
setStyle(value: string): void {
console.log('read More Works');
this.aColor = '#yellow';
console.log('read More still Works');
  }
```

and that is it. Clicking on 'Some Button' button does not do anything except the logging but I am pretty sure it is not two way binding that is the issue as I tried just using for example trying with just some text as being the 'variable' I want to change and that worked fine.

I do appreciate any help :(
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre defined CSS styles for that. Something like this:

`card.page.scss`

```
#somediv {
    &.initial-style {
        background: #000;
    }

    &.dinamic-style {
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

`card.page.html`

```
<div id="somediv" [class]="apply_styles ? 'dinamic-style' : 'initial-style'">
   styles applied: {{ apply_styles }}
</div>

<ion-button (click)="changeStyle()">Change Style</ion-button>
```

`card.page.ts`

```
apply_styles: boolean = false;

changeStyle() {
   this.apply_styles = !this.apply_styles;
}
```

Of course this is very simple. But I hope it can put you in the right direction.